# Changing the surface reflectance values of Landsat 8

Tags: google-earth-engine

How do I change the surface reflectance values of a Landsat 8 image to scale it between 0 and 1 ?
I am using Google Earth Engine to perform this ?
How do I achieve this ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

> Scale it between 0 and 1

This is called normalization.
See this code for Landsat 8 collection 2, all bands are normalized.

```
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2')
.filter(ee.Filter.date('2021-01-01', '2021-02-01'))
.filter(ee.Filter.bounds(geometry))

var test = ee.Image(dataset.first())


function normalize(image){
  // Normalization code adopted from 
  // https://courses.spatialthoughts.com/end-to-end-gee.html#image-normalization-and-standardization
  
  var bandNames = image.bandNames();
  // Compute min and max of the image
  var minDict = image.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.min(),
    geometry: geometry,
    scale: 30,
    maxPixels: 1e9,
    bestEffort: true,
    tileScale: 16
  });
  var maxDict = image.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.max(),
    geometry: geometry,
    scale: 30,
    maxPixels: 1e9,
    bestEffort: true,
    tileScale: 16
  });
  var mins = ee.Image.constant(minDict.values(bandNames));
  var maxs = ee.Image.constant(maxDict.values(bandNames));

  var normalized = image.subtract(mins).divide(maxs.subtract(mins))
  return normalized
}

var normalisedImage = normalize(test)
print(normalisedImage)
```

---

code link : https://code.earthengine.google.com/3b05285d7e9cbded5c7854eac9d4ddb5